# What is the difference between ffmpeg and ffmbc now?

Tags: ffmpeg

Two years ago I've used ffmbc to encode videos to prores, but nowadays ffmpeg also supports [prores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_ProRes) and [avchd](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Video_Codec_High_Definition). What is the difference between [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) and [ffmbc](https://code.google.com/p/ffmbc/) now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Usage differences

<sub>Note: `ffmbc`/`ffmpeg` will refer to the tools, while FFmbc/FFmpeg will refer to the projects themselves and/or each whole collection of tools and libraries.</sub>

- There are syntax differences including:

  - `ffmbc` uses the old, confusing `-newaudio` option while `ffmpeg` can just use `-map`.
  - `ffmbc` does not support `-codec` or `-c`, so instead all stream types must be explicitly defined if you do not want to rely on the defaults. For example `-vcodec copy -acodec copy -scodec copy` vs just `-c copy`.
  - Probably lots more that I didn't think of. Feel free to edit answer and add more.
- `ffmbc` will automatically relocate some data after encoding to MOV, MP4, etc while `ffmpeg` requires the `-movflags +faststart` option.
- `ffmbc` does not support `-filter_complex` so filtering is different. For example, using the overlay video filter:

  - `ffmbc`: `-i video.mp4 -vf "movie='overlay.png' [movie]; [in][movie] overlay [out]"`
  - `ffmpeg`: `-i video.mp4 -i image.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay"`
- FFmbc seems to support more broadcast formats.
- FFmpeg has more features and filters.
- FFmbc dropped `ffplay` and `ffserver`.

## Development differences

- FFmbc is GPL, and FFmpeg is mostly LGPL which makes porting features from FFmbc to FFmpeg more difficult.
- FFmbc is basically the project of a former FFmpeg developer with a few contributions from others. FFmpeg has many developers and contributors.
- FFmpeg often merges things form Libav, while FFmbc ignores Libav. Libav cherry-picks occasionally from FFmpeg, but ignores most stuff from FFmpeg (Libav is often joked to have "[NIH syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)").

Answer (score 4):

One difference at least :

```
-target xdcamhd422
```

is supported by FFmbc but not by FFmpeg.

Very useful in a professional broadcast environment.

the `-target` option allows to specify several parameters at once. The `-target` option value must be one supported by FFm**. In the case of the `xdcamhd422` value, it specifies the video codec to be used (`mpeg2video`), the frame size (1920 x 1080), and other parameters in order to have an output file conform to the XDCam HD standard.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly you can do with it? Convert it to sony xdcam mxf, right?

Comment: You're welcome. Added a few precisions in the answer. I used it to produce test files for a professional playout server and it worked perfectly.